# Skype - Unable to receive group chat messages

Tags: ubuntu, skype

My Skype is working almost completely. I can send files, make and receive calls and chats normally. However, I don't receive messages from chat groups that have been created recently.

What I have tried:

1. remove my ~/.Skype folder;
2. reinstall another version from ubuntu repositories (32 and 64 bits);
3. firewall rules;
4. proxy is fine as other users are successfully talking.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits and Skype 4.3.0.37-1 32 bits but this problem seems to happen even on Windows ([here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/I-can-t-receive-or-send-messages-in-my-group/td-p/3685893) and [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Group-chat-features-not-working-anymore/td-p/3950730))

It seems to be related to cloud group chats.

I don't receive messages from groups whose name starts with "19:xxxx". However I receive from groups whose name starts with $ or something else.

The following command returns the group name:

```
/get name
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I will answer my own question... I hope this will help someone! :)

After struggling a bit, I found some useful commands:

- `/dumpmsnp` - show details about your connection
- `/showplaces` - show where you are currently connected

You can execute them in any chat window.

`/dumpmsnp` command was showing "**LoggedOut**", but I was online and talking almost normally (except group chats).

```
System: MSNP: Connection Data:
 * Status: LoggedOut
```

A lot of people are/were suffering from this problem ([here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Group-chat-stopped-working-suddenly-on-Linux/td-p/4071600)).

To solve this "LoggedOut" issue, try this on any chat window:

```
/msnp24
```

and restart your Skype.

After restarting, `/dumpmsnp` output shows the following status:

```
System: MSNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
 * Status: LoggedIn
```

I don't know exactly why, but the `/msnp24` command kinds of converted my account to this protocol and now everything works perfectly.

I've found the solution [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/New-chat-groups-not-showing-up-in-client/td-p/3206434).

Comment: Awesome!!! Magical!! take a bow!!!

Comment: Confirmed works. You need to make sure there are no spaces after the command. Thanks!!

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! I've been struggling with this soo much. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 9):

/msnp24 doesn't works for me, but problem solved.

If you vi **~/.Skype/<your_skype_username>/config.xml**, then navigate to the **HomeServer** tags, you will see something similar to:

```
<MSNPCore>
  <HomeServer>BAYMSGR2013521.gateway.messenger.live.com</HomeServer>
  <NewThreadAllowed>1</NewThreadAllowed>
  <P2PMigrationAllowed>0</P2PMigrationAllowed>
  <ProtocolToUse>24</ProtocolToUse>
```

Now test this HomeServer's hostname with `traceroute` command, e.g. `traceroute BAYMSGR2013521.gateway.messenger.live.com` above, the last line will got to *** which might because of firewall blocking. So just:

1. Ensure you close any running skype instance(check by `ps aux` and `kill -9 skype_PID`).
2. Delete the **HomeServer** tags in config.xml. Either empty the tags or delete the line should works. Save the file.
3. Start the skype. It should able to send and receive group chat messages now.
4. Check config.xml again, the tags should automatically updated with new hostname.
5. If you test this new hostname with traceroute, it should go to last line which are not ***.

Comment: Thanks for improving even more this issue. It can be an alternative for someone else.

Comment: I combined this answer with the previous one and it worked perfectly for me! I avoided clearing my Skype chat.