# What exactly is msnp24 in relation to Skype

Tags: skype

I was having a strange problem with my Skype where I could use 1-1 conversations normally, but I could not take part in, or even see, group conversations.

Following the accepted solution in [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/989815/skype-unable-to-receive-group-chat-messages), I was able to solve my problem very easily.

I quote the answer here in case it vanishes or is edited.

> After struggling a bit, I found some useful commands. You can type these in any skype chat window.
>
> /dumpmsnp - show details about your connection
>   /showplaces - show where you are currently connected
>
> What was happening was that /dumpmsnp command was showing "LoggedOut", but I was online and talking almost normally (except group chats).
>
> System: MSNP: Connection Data:
>   * Status: LoggedOut
>
> To solve this "LoggedOut" issue, try this on any chat window:
>
> /msnp24
>
> and restart your Skype.
>
> After restarting, /dumpmsnp output shows the following status:
>
> System: MSNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
>   * Status: LoggedIn
>
> I don't know exactly why, but the /msnp24 command kinds of converted my account to this protocol and now everything works perfectly.

A pet hate of mine, however, is solving a problem without understanding how it was solved. So I am very curious what was actually going on behind the scenes.

My question is this: Can someone please explain what exactly was happening, why Skype behaved in this way, and why typing `/msnp24` followed by a logout/in cycle fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Notification Protocol

"Microsoft Notification Protocol (MSNP, also known as the Mobile Status Notification Protocol) is an instant messaging protocol developed by Microsoft for use by the Microsoft Messenger service and the instant messaging clients that connect to it, such as Skype since 2014, and the earlier Windows Live Messenger, MSN Messenger, Windows Messenger, and Microsoft Messenger for Mac. Third-party clients such as Pidgin and Trillian can also communicate using the protocol. MSNP was first used in a publicly available product with the first release of MSN Messenger in 1999." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notification_Protocol)

This command resets this protocol.  I am not sure why you had to relogin.  I would assume restarting skype would have the same effect.